# Help cleaning up dozens of duplicate 'facebook meta image' questions

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, facebook, clean-up

I just listened to Stack Exchange Podcast #20 where Joel and Jeff talk about the problems with duplicate questions and how Joel would prefer a [single good canonical answer](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/6949/forming-a-new-software-startup-how-do-i-allocate-ownership-fairly/23326#23326) that duplicate questions can be pointed to.  The problem with Facebook questions is that there are a ton coming in but very low view count, and even less flag count so I am asking for help in getting the necessary votes to clean these up.

The biggest problem question is "how do I set the thumbnail image for my page?", with a slight variation of it being "why isn't my thumbnail image updating".  **I need the community's help closing these as duplicate**.  Here are 25 duplicate questions pulled from the first 3 pages of Google results (there are lots more though):

**Best duplicate target:**
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images

**List of duplicates:** (feel free to update this list or remove entries once they get closed)

- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7589553/image-meta-tag-not-showing-up-in-post</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4575938/facebook-like-meta-tags-not-showing-images</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7540766/like-button-on-my-site-publishes-a-picture-that-i-didnt-want-to</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7565361/correcting-fb-meta-tags-not-showing-correct-image</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7589877/facebook-like-meta-tags-not-showing-correct-image</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3623907/facebook-like-not-extracting-right-image-from-meta-tags</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7324358/help-with-the-order-of-ogimage-meta-tag</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7589877/facebook-like-meta-tags-not-showing-correct-image</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7477478/how-to-set-image-description-and-title-for-each-facebook-like-in-a-wordpress-blo</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7572441/facebook-like-showing-cached-version-ogimage-way-to-refresh-or-reindex-it</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7517794/facebook-connect-debugger-and-site-wont-use-meta-tags</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7392080/problem-defining-ogimage-path-for-php-generated-open-graph-meta-tags-product-i</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2400947/want-custom-title-image-description-in-facebook-share-link-from-a-flash-app</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3944268/facebook-sharer-php-how-to-have-multiple-ogimage-tags</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5257075/facebook-share-button-with-custom-title-description-and-image</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4967979/facebook-share-url-thumbnail-problem</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6019057/using-facebooks-open-graph-protocol-are-multiple-thumbnail-images-allowed</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5951295/facebook-image-sharing-problem</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6641440/image-tags-for-google-or-facebook</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7245381/facebook-send-button-picture-not-showing</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5470225/facebook-will-not-display-the-image-from-my-page-as-a-thumbnail-when-posting-it</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4714979/facebook-like-button-specify-graphic-for-this-page</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7584440/facebook-seo-with-image-not-loading</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7578069/like-button-make-facebook-not-take-specific-images</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2846381/what-does-ogimage-meta-data-do-with-the-facebook-like-iframe</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7304921/facebook-like-button-image-not-shown-on-news-feed</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6376032/ogimage-wont-show-up-in-my-facebook-feed-connected-to-like-button-on-my-site</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3898421/ogimage-wont-show-up-in-my-facebook-feed-when-i-like-stuff-at-my-site</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7193403/facebook-same-meta-tags-worked-on-one-host-and-not-worked-on-another</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7479157/og-image-not-being-displayed-in-arts-and-entertainment-page</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5685850/can-i-make-a-change-to-my-website-to-nominate-an-image-to-be-used-by-facebook</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5815443/auto-update-image-of-a-shared-link-on-fan-wall</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7341260/like-button-results-in-odd-image-on-wall-post</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5888638/facebook-like-button-fetches-wrong-image</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6530420/control-the-image-that-facebook-shows-when-i-like-a-url</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5592140/how-to-chose-custom-image-that-will-be-shared-on-facebook-after-liking-a-page</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5148005/update-on-adding-custom-image-to-facebook-share</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3604987/how-does-facebook-know-what-images-are-needed-to-get-from-a-url</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197696/facebook-sharer-wont-embed-image-in-ie</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7247303/facebook-wont-show-my-ohimage-thumbnails-no-matter-what-i-do</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5173900/facebook-open-graph-displays-image-even-though-picture-parameter-not-sent</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7402751/providing-a-set-of-images-to-use-as-thumbnail-when-sharing-a-url</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6704000/fb-share-and-picture-problem</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1558802/how-do-i-control-what-images-facebook-attaches-to-the-feed-story-when-my-website</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7352687/how-to-tell-facebook-what-images-to-offer-a-user-when-posting-a-link-to-my-web-pa</s>
- <s>http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6042502/how-to-control-the-picture-that-shows-in-facebook-when-somebody-likes-your-blog-p</s>

Comment: Ok, the problem is Lasse (a moderator) closed it and then re-opened it immediately, clearing our close votes. Since we already voted to close once, we can't again. Can you  take another look -- it looks to me like it's a problem with getting status 500, not with anything actually related to the duplicate we've been selecting. Maybe that's why?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for all the close votes.  They have all been cleaned up or closed.